# Deadline where string is located

Tags: python, readlines

Is it possible to read a line where a word is located? I've got an input and I want Python to search a username-file for the ID I put in. For example I enter '1111' and in line 8 in file is written '1111 Example'. Now I want it to print this line! How to do this or is it impossible?

Comment: Of course it's possible, but general consensus here is that we won't write your code for you. So start from opening a file, having a for loop go through the lines, write how you'd match a string in the line and how would you print it. Come back with something, doesn't have to be very good or fast, and then we'll help you write it better/faster/more readable and give you tips.

Comment: Of course, anything is possible. Programming is an art in which you devise an algorithm to do as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

`with open() as` opens and automatically closes the file when you are done.

Then you iterate through each line in the file. If the file contains `1111` you print it. You can change `1111` to anything you like.

```
with open('my_text_file.txt', 'r') as f:

    for line in f:            
        if '1111' in line:
            print(line)
```

Just change `'my_text_file.txt'` to anything you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would just open the file, split it into lines, and then filter for the username. So if the file is just lines of "userid username", you can do this:

```
class Usernames:
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.filehandle = open(filepath, 'r')
        self.lines = self.filehandle.readlines()
    def __del__(self):
        self.filehandle.close()
    def get_user(user_id):
        def match_on_first(line):
            return user_id == line.split(' ')[0]
        return filter(match_on_first, self.lines)
```

That should return all the lines which match the user id. Let me know if you need more help.